# Using enums from one controllers model for logic checks in another controllers model

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public function approve($id = null, $user = true ) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid article'));
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid article'));
        }

        if ($user['role'] == 'moderator') {
            $this->Post->saveField("approval",'Approved by Moderator');
        }
        elseif ($user['role'] == 'admin') {
            $this->Post->saveField("approval",'Posted!');
        }
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index');
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the current user's "role" (`$user['role']`), which is an enum, to dictate what the action does. However I can't seem to get this to work.

Do I have to do something differently to make sure it knows that the controller needs to use the User model?

Comment: where do you get `$user` variable from? Usually you have to get it from Session  `$user = $this->Session->read('Auth.user');`

Comment: I have it set up in AppController, I thought it would cascade down. When I echo $current_user[role] or $user[role] in a view I get the right value, but how come this doesn't work the same in a controller function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AppController` it seems you have something like

```
$this->set('user', $user);
```

You should also add

```
public $loggedUser;
```

and then

```
$this->loggedUser = $user;
```

This way, you are sending `loggedUser` to all controllers.

In the `PostsController`, you need

```
if ($this->loggedUser['role'] == 'moderator') {  
     // ..
}
```

Please note that you can easily work with the logged user info inside any controller with

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

You can have

```
if $this->Auth->user('role') == 'moderator')  {
    // ...
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

Comment: In fact, using `Auth` should be the way to go

Comment: Yes, auth is a lot easier and makes more sense. But if he wants to send other data to all controllers, he can use the `AppController`